# Golang array and map synchronization over network

Tags: networking, go, synchronization

I have a need to synchronize an internal state of 2 programs(client && server) over the persistent network connection.

The first idea was to implement a custom protocol for this, is there any alternatives you can think of? Any libraries that could help in the process?

Internal state consists of a lot of maps and slices, when some structure inside slice/map changes it would be okay to pass it as a whole

Answer (score 0):

package encoding/gob maybe helpful if only for golang

Comment: this solves only serialization aspect of the task, I'm checking is there anything that could handle the whole way of serializing, passing over network, deserializing

Comment: net/rpc it's that you want?

Comment: this might be closer hit =) With some glue code for detecting changes in slices && maps it could solve the task I guess

Comment: use only some function to modify slice/maps, those functions should also notify the changes of slice/map.